# Installing Hive (Hadoop) on windows (Cygwin)

Tags: windows, hadoop, cygwin, hive

I've just installed hadoop on windows using cygwin which works fine, and now I am installing [Hive](http://hive.apache.org/). I am running it as:

```
bin/hive -hiveconf java.io.tmpdir=/cygdrive/c/cygwin/tmp
OR
bin/hive -hiveconf java.io.tmpdir=/tmp
```

(both give the same problem) as I have found out there is a bug with the windows naming convension ([https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-2388...](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-2388?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3aall-tabpanel))

When I run the above command, Hive seems to load fine, but when I enter "`show tables;`" I get no response. This is the same for all queries. `CREATE TABLE` etc, there is no response

Its the same problem as this guy:
[http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox...](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/hive-user/201209.mbox/%3CF0232037B611204D9A7090EC62CF180B055F0480F1@nda-hclt-evs06.HCLT.CORP.HCL.IN%3E)

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you confirm you've actually created a table? Until you do this, SHOW TABLES won't return anything.

Comment: Every query hangs, there is no response from any query I make. Create table or whatever

Answer (score 1):

I resolved a similar issue and successfully ran HIVE after starting all Hadoop daemons

- namenode
- datanode
- jobtracker
- Task Tracker

Running queries from files using `hive -f <filename>`, instead of writing queries directly at the HIVE command prompt. Additionally, you may also use `bin/hive -e 'SHOW TABLES'`

Comment: Hi Madhu, I am trying to run the system on windows/cygwin on local mode. Not even pseudo mode. So I don't have NN, DN, JT and TT running on my system. More over when go to grunt or hive shell and type a command it literally hangs. I am not sure what is wrong with it. I've added more information to the question here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18010482/hive-and-pig-grunt-shell-hangs-on-cygwin Please check if you have some inputs.